# afterTextChanged() callback being called without the text being actually changed

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a fragment with an `EditText` and inside the `onCreateView()` I add a `TextWatcher` to the `EditText`.

Each time the fragment is being added for the second time `afterTextChanged(Editable s)` callback is being called without the text ever being changed.

Here is a code snippet :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    myEditText = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
...
}

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        searchProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.d(TAG, "after text changed");
    }
}
```

I also set the fragment to retain its state, and I keep the instance of the fragment in the activity.

Comment: *Each time the fragment is being added for the second time* - can you share some code related to this?

Comment: It is a very common thing to do when switching fragments.

transaction.replace(r.id.container, fragment);
transaction.commit();

nothing special, I have solved the problem with adding a flag I will  be posting a solution.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Edited solution:**

As it seems the text was changed from the second time the fragment was attached because the fragment restored the previous state of the views.

My solution was adding the `text watcher` in the `onResume()` since the state was restored **before** the `onResume` was called.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
}
```

**Edit**
As @MiloszTylenda have mentioned in the comments it is better to remove the `Textwatcher` in the `onPause()` callback to avoid leaking the `Textwatcher`.

```
@Override public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
  myEditText.removeTextChangedListener(watcher);
}
```

Comment: Great, that fixed it for me!

Comment: Thank you. This was driving me absolutely crazy.

Comment: This solution is not ideal either. Now every time your fragment comes to foreground the `textWatcher` is re-added and you end up with multiple watcher references in the `myEditText`. This causes the `afterTextChanged()` method being invoked twice after each text modification. See the source of `TextView.addTextChangedListener` in the framework.

Comment: @MiloszTylenda so the proper answer would be removing the text watcher during onPause. I will edit the answer! thanks.

Comment: I think you should add the addTextChangedListener in Fragment's onViewCreated

Comment: @HauLuu it was the issue from the start, of doing it in the onViewCreated.

Comment: @meh it does work. why it does not work if done in onViewCreated/onDestroyView (adding/removing text watchers)?

Comment: i have implemented textwatcher from the adapter class. Now how can i access onPause and onResume method from adapter?

Answer (score 13):

It seems that this error comes from the fact that Android SDK will call settext when view is coming alive again to recover the state of the EditText.
As you can see from the extract below there is a flag that you can change on the Edittext to bypass this behavior.

```
    <!-- If false, no state will be saved for this view when it is being
         frozen. The default is true, allowing the view to be saved
         (however it also must have an ID assigned to it for its
         state to be saved).  Setting this to false only disables the
         state for this view, not for its children which may still
         be saved. -->
    <attr name="saveEnabled" format="boolean" />
```

So by adding     `android:saveEnabled="false"` on your EditText will fix the problem and the setText will not be called when view comes to foreground.

This is what I did and problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Kotlin extension function code to efficiently add an `afterTextChanged` listener to a `TextView` within the context of a `Fragment`'s view lifecycle. This approach ensures that the listener is added during the `onResume` event and removed during `onPause`, contributing to better memory management and reduced potential leaks.

The code below defines an extension function `doAfterTextChanged` for a `TextView` with this lifecycle-aware behavior. It relies on the `SimpleTextWatcher` interface to implement the text change logic.

```
fun TextView.doAfterTextChanged(
    fragment: Fragment,
    callback: (Editable?) -> Unit,
) {
    val textWatcher = object : SimpleTextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {
            callback(text)
        }
    }

    fragment.viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(object : DefaultLifecycleObserver {
        override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        }

        override fun onPause(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher)
        }
    })
}

interface SimpleTextWatcher : TextWatcher {
    override fun beforeTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
    override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {}
    override fun afterTextChanged(text: Editable?) {}
}
```