# addTextChangedListener and onTextChanged are always called when Android Fragment loads

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `EditText` in an Android `Fragment`. I attach `addTextChangedListener` to it in the `onCreateView` method. Within the `addTextChangedListener` I have an `onTextChanged` method. By logging, I can see that every time the `Fragment` is loaded, `onTextChanged` is called. Why would this be? I only want it to be called when the user actually changes the text in the `EditText`. Here's my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);
    final EditText notes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.stitchnotes);
notes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            Edited = true;
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721063/aftertextchanged-callback-being-called-without-the-text-being-actually-changed) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13303469/edittext-settext-not-working-with-fragment) and I'm wondering if I should move my code to `onResume`. However, as you can see from the above code, I need access to the `LayoutInflater` and `ViewGroup` passed to `onCreateView` in order to access the `EditText`; however, `onResume` doesn't normally have access to these items. Should I be using `onResume`? How do I handle the issue with the `LayoutInflater` and `ViewGroup`?

-----------------Further Information----------------------

I used Tyler's answer to solve the problem of how to use `onResume`, but onTextChanged is still being called when I first open the `Fragment`. Can someone explain why?  Here's my modified code:

```
private EditText notes;
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);
    notes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.stitchnotes);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    notes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                int before, int count) {
            Edited = true;
            Log.w("onTextChanged","Here");
        }
    });
}

<EditText
        android:id="@+id/stitchnotes"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="@string/hint"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="30dip" />
```

The moment I open the `Fragment,` `Edited` is set to true and the LogCat is written to. I don't want this. I want `Edited` to be set to true only when the user actually types something in the `EditText`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the `EditText` have any default text in it defined in the XML layout? What is the text actually being set to in the `onTextChanged()` method?

Comment: No default text. There is a hint. Could that be it? I've added the XML for the EditText above.

Comment: BTW - I took the hint out, but no joy. It still behaves the same way.

Comment: In the debugger (or by printing to the log) can you check what the new text value is (the `s` variable)? It might offer up a clue as to what's happening.

Comment: Strange. When I output "Here" in the log, it gets output the minute I open the Fragment. When I output s.toString, however, it only gets output when I start writing in the EditText. No matter which way I go, though, Edited gets set to true the minute I open the Fragment, and the value of Edited is really what I'm going for here.

Comment: unluddite - thank you for getting my wheels turning. I dropped the idea of the Edited variable and added two new variables to my class: strEditTextBefore, which I assigned the value of notes.toString in the onCreateView method, and strEditTextAfter, which I assigned the value of s.toString in the onResume method. I then compared them at the point in my code when I wanted to see if the user had edited the text. It works perfectly. Again, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your `EditText` a member of the class. Or, make the `View` a member of the class and call `findViewById` later.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText notes;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle     savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detailfragment, container, false);
        notes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.stitchnotes);
        // your other stuff
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        notes.setText("Now I can access my EditText!");
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, Tyler - that's painfully obvious. I'll give this a shot and see if it solves my issue with onTextChanged always being called.

Answer (score 17):

I got same problem but in adapter. The above solution is working fine for the direct child of the view but in list view adapter I have problem.
Finally I found the solution with focus change.

```
 editQty.setTag(false);
    editQty.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            editQty.setTag(true);
        }
    });
    editQty.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (!s.toString().equals("") && (Boolean) editQty.getTag()) {
               // Do your Logic here
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Small And Simple**

> Basically in this case when fragment loads onTextChanged character sequence return "" which is not empty string so this will gives you some better idea

```
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



            if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {

               //control come here when user enter some string to edit text

            } else {

                  //When fragment loads control comes here but below condition prevents execution because s.toString() give ""

                if (!s.toString().equals("")) {




                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: This doesnt account for the fact that the user may delete all the text and therefore s.toString() will be empty

Comment: I use  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(editable.toString())){} to handle empty or  null string.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it adding it in Handler().postDelayed() in onViewCreated. Example : (Kotlin)

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
            binding?.searchEdit?.doAfterTextChanged {
                
            }
        }, 100)
```

Answer (score -1):

public class FeedbackFragment extends SherlockFragment {

```
private EditText mEtFeedback;
CustomTextWatcher obj;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feedback_layout, container, false);
initUIComponents();
obj=new CustomTextWatcher();
mEtFeedback.addTextChangedListener(obj);

return view;
}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDestroy();
mEtFeedback.removeTextChangedListener(obj);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
switch (v.getId()) {

default:
    break;
}

}
class CustomTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {



    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

}