# Fragment's EditTexts are triggered when it is replaced

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-edittext, focus

So, I have this problem: I am initializing a fragment - `AddingTaskFragment`
here's code:

### Initializing AddingTaskFragment

```
 private void initFragment()
    {
        // Get fragment manager
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        // Begin transaction
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        // Create the Fragment and add
        addingTaskFragment = new AddingTaskFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_task_type_container, addingTaskFragment, "addTaskFragment");
       // ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

        // Commit the changes
        ft.commit();
    }
```

And it works fine [image: image of AddingTaskFragment]
But then, I call some event, that replaces this fragment with other one(`AddingScheduleFragment`).

### Replacing fragment

```
@Override
    public void onScheduleTypePick()
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

        // Create the fragment and attach book index
        addingScheduleFragment = new AddingScheduleFragment();

        // Replace the book list with the description
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_task_type_container, addingScheduleFragment, "addScheduleFragment");
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

And when I'm poping my previous fragment(`AddingTaskFragment`) from the stack. All of my `EditViews` are gaining focus.

### Returning previous fragment

```
 @Override
    public void onTaskTypePick()
    {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
```

[image: fragment after returning from stack]

What can be wrong? Why is this happening? Thanks for answers.

Important: When I replacing AddingTaskFragent with new object everything works great.

Comment: post your layout xml..

Comment: @rafsanahmad007, of AddingTaskFragment? https://paste.ofcode.org/3aV9X9WdnGZcQ5rzaKLZWbm

Comment: I've discovered one thing: I have a listeners on every `EditText` - `afterTextChanged` and when I remove them, everything is fine. Why is it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've solved the problem by myself. Rather found the similar one.

[afterTextChanged() callback being called without the text being actually changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721063/aftertextchanged-callback-being-called-without-the-text-being-actually-changed)

When the fragment was attached second time(because of `.replace()` method) it was restoring the previous state of the views. And then all textChangeListeners triggered.